# Is Shankaracharya's Advaita Vedanta philosophy compatible with Vaishnavism?

Tags: vaishnavism, advaita, adi-shankaracharya

There are many schools of thought like VisistAdvaita, Achintya Bheda Abheda and Dvaita which are followed by different sects of Vaishnavites. Most of these Vaishnava sects seem to be very critical of Advaita as they see it alien to their beliefs. However, I am a Vaishnava myself and attracted to Advaita Vedanta. Can I be both an Advaitin and Vaishnava?

Comment: Your observation is mostly correct. Being a Vaishnav myself, it seems strictly "no-no" for a Vaishnav to be in believing Advaita. Many Vaishnava are leaned towards celebrating colorful life of Shri Krishna. For them Advaita will be too bland. My personal opinion is that *Advaita* is the highest state towards realisation. It's a "state" rather than a "philosophy".

Comment: Not all Vaishnavas are dualistic i.e., follow Dvaita. For instance, SriVaishnavas are proponents of VisistAdvaita.

Comment: Vaishnavas are _not_ SriVaishnavas, they are neither a superset nor a subset. Vaishnavas who follow Madhvacharya are a specific sect who are dualistic and not to be confused with all followers of Vishnu. @Surya Kanta, it would be useful to add more detail to your question about what exactly you mean when you say Vaishnavas. There are numerous sects who worship Vishnu with different philosophies.

Comment: @user1952500 Why do you say that? It is patent that SriVaishnavas are part of the larger category of Vaishnavas.

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan it is quite a difficult topic and maybe someone better at understanding it and explaining it can answer the question better. On a superficial level, Advaita believes in one Atman, Dvaita believes in a Jivatman and Paramatman and Vishishtadwaita believes in a Jivatman, Paramatman and _Prakruti_. Each of these philosophies differ in the way they interpret the BrahmaSutras among other things. Vishishtadwaita is a separate interpretation of the Brahmasutras by Ramanuja and not a mere extension of Dwaita.

Comment: @user1952500 The point i was trying to make is that Vaishnavam encompasses different schools of thought. Contrary to your initial objection, I never said that one must be subset of another or viceversa. Hopefully this is clear.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury VisistAdvaita is not between Dualism and Non-Dualism like you claim, it is also non-dualistic school of thought.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan Then can you edit the question? I am illiterate in Vedanta.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan sorry I misunderstood and thanks for clarifying. I cannot edit my comment anymore. In the south (or maybe among the SriVaishnavas), a Vaishnava specifically means a person of the Dwaita philosophy (Madhvacharya). We do not call a person who is a SriVaishnava as a Vaishnava (though it means a follower of Vishnu). The term is reserved for the followers of Dwaita. It is tough to know if this is a generic distinction because there is no good statistical reference. Please do let me know if people around you use this term as a generic term referring to all sects following Vishnu.

Comment: @user1952500 No problem. AFAIK, SriVaishnavas and other sects of Vaishnavas come under the generic/categorical label of Vaishnavas.

Comment: there is a quote from Sankara or Gaudapada that says the advaita has no argument with dvaita, it is only followers of dvaita that have a problem with advaita. I am traveling for the next week and don't have access to my books so can't find for another week.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda yeah, Gaudapada karika on Mandukya Upanishad has those verses.

Comment: @Pandya - Gaudapada karika - Advaita Prakaran - Shloka -17-18

Comment: "Most of these Vaishnava sects seem to be fiercely anti-Advaita as they think Advaita philosophy is alien in their beliefs." Neither accurate nor of value to the question.

Comment: Many Advaitins, followers of Shankara's Advaita system of Vedanta, say that they are Vaishnavas, meaning they are worshipers of Lord Vishnu. So they believe it is possible to be a worshiper of Lord Vishnu and an Advaitin. On the other hand in Vaishnava sampradayas (traditions) such as Ramanuja's, Madhvas, Gaudiya Vaishnava, etc, they also say that they are Vaishnavas, ie worshipers of Lord Vishnu, but their belief systems of Vedanta differ substantially from Shankara's Advaita. ...

Comment: ... They differ so much that they opposed many of the points of teaching of Advaita system. Thus systems of Vedanta of Vaishnava sampradayas are not compatible with Advaita system of Vedanta. In such circumstances it would be impossible to be a follower of a Vaishnava sampradaya and believer in Shankara's Advaita system of Vedanta. By the way, Shankara also opposed many of the points of teaching of Vaishnava belief systems. So it's quite clear that Shankara's beliefs and Vaishnava sampradayas' beliefs are much opposed and not compatible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Advaitha is too generic, you can be almost anything, when you are an Advaithi.

Besides, Adi Shankaracharya himself was a Vaishnava, he composed many stotrams on the highest Lord as Vishnu. And confusingly enough he was also a Shaktha, Shaiva etc.

Because one of the core philosophies of Advaitha is that the same ethereal Brahman underlies all existence and all forms. So yes, you can be an Advaithi and a Vaishnava.

Comment: a vishnu devotee is not necessarily a vaishnavite. a vaishnavite believes vishnu alone is the supreme deity.  a false idea has been spread by vaishnavites about adi sankara that he was a vaishnavite.  some people say that vishnu was his ista-devata which is not the same as his being a vaishnavite.  sankara didn't agree with pancharatra agamas- hardly a vaishnavite position.

Answer (score 3):

Who says that one can't be a Advaitavadin & a Vaishnava together ?

Âdi Shankaracharya had written commentaries of Vishnu Sahasranâma & Bhagavadgîtâ.

Srîdhara Svami, the first commentator of the Srimad Bhâgavatam & Vishnu Purâna, was the disciple of an Advaita monk named Paramânanda Purî.

Madhusûdana Sarasvatî, a renowned Advaita scholar who composed a text named 'Advaitasiddhi' aline-by-line refutal of an Dvaita text named 'Nyayâmruta' composed by Madhva-scholar Vyasatirtha, who had close connections with the Vijayanagara emperors, along with other works defending Advaita philosophy from criticism like 'Advaitamanjarî', 'Advaitaratnarakshana'; had also composed commentaries on the Shandilya Bhaktisutra & Shivamahimna stotra  along with works like 'Krishna kutuhala nataka', 'Bhakti sâmânya nirûpana', 'Hari lîlâ vyâkhyâ' & 'Ânandamandakinî' which exposes his deep devotion to Sri Krishna.

The animosity of almost all schools of Vaishnava theology towards Advaita philosophy arises from the fact that Ramanuja & Madhva had decried Shaiva doctrines as heresy & Adi Shankara, who is regarded to be an incarnation of Bhagavâna Shiva in Advaita circles, to be a crypto-Buddhist.

In order to be Vaishnava as well as an Advaitavâdin, it is better to study the Srimad Bhâgavatam along with the commentary of Sridhara Svami & the Bhagavadgîta along with the commentary of Madhusûdana Sarasvati.

Comment: Very interesting, I never knew famous acharyas thought Shankara to be a crypto-Buddhist, especially since he toured throughout the country, debating and defeating Buddhists, and establishing the Hindu philosophy and way of life everywhere he went. Could you please add some references/links? I am interested in knowing more about this topic.

Comment: (http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=1323&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1), (http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=1111&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1), (http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=937&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1), (http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=596&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1), (http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=566&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1), (http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=546&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1), (http://www.kamakotimandali.com/blog/index.php?p=540&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1) -- here are the links you asked for. Read especially the 2nd link

Comment: Thanks for the links. Good Answer. Upvoted.

Comment: By the way, these links are based exclusively on the commentaries (opinions really) of Western scholars/indologists, who cannot be trusted, as they are agenda driven, funded by church funded institutions. A simple strategy to divide the practitioners of Hinduism. For example, One of the links tried to argue that the words/philosophical vocabulary were common, so Sankara must have borrowed. This is absurd, since there are many different meanings of the same sanskrit word depending upon the context. For example, dharma may mean law, or duty, or miniscule particles (Theravada Buddhism, I think)

Comment: Another example: Moksha in arthashastra means divorce, not liberation.

Comment: That's a problem with some people nowadays. They are never interested in researching their own religion but if any foreigner does it, then that person is damned without even reading his/her works because that person is a foreigner. Not all people all like Wendy Doniger, there are also people like Sir John Woodroffe but these people will damn both of them because they are mlecchas. Scondly arthasastra isn't a religious text, so it's reference is invalid while discussing religious matters.

Comment: What problem do you have if Adi Shankara borrowed concepts for elsewhere(like Mandukya Karika). Knowledge is not the paternal property of any particular person or sect.

Comment: Don't get sentimental, please stay objective. I respect some western scholars more than Indian born ones. For example, I respect Dr. David Frawley, Dr. Koenraad Elst, Francis Gautier more than Indian scholars like Dr. S. Radhakrishnan, or Devdutt Patnaik. 
The problem is that the genuinely interested western scholars are very few in number, and their motive is not to flood the markets and academia with false propoganda, suiting their religious/socio-political interest. Hence, what reaches the common folks are the ill-motivated work and it infuences our knowledge.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119148/discussion-between-iamthat-and-anubrata-bit).

Answer (score 2):

Warakari sampradaya of Maharashtra, who are devotee of Vitthal ( Krishna ) follows advait philosophy with bhakti of krishna. They are biggest vaishnavas in Maharashtra and one of the biggest Vaishnava sect overall.

There are lot of Vaishnavas who are philosophically inclined towards advait nature of Paramtatva.